# SingleChildScrollView won't work? Placement?

Tags: flutter

I have a card I am displaying with some info. I want to wrap it in a SingleChildScrollView as I have more items to add to the card, but when I do the screen just blanks out? I have tried putting it as root (Scaffold body) and before the Card but it won't work?

```
 return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: globals.pageBackgroundColor,
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Company name'),
            leading: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, true);
                })),
        body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Card(
                child: Container(
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(color: globals.widgetBackgroundColor),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          height: 120,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                                  child: Container(
                                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      child: Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/200"))),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 20, 10, 0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text('Company name',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 18,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                        Text('Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum')
                                      ],
                                    )),
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 20, right: 20),
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text('Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25)),
                                Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.thumb_up,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20)),
                                    Text('Lorem ipsum lorem',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: globals.cardSubTitleColor,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 18))
                                  ],
                                )
                              ]),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
                      Expanded(
                              child: GridView.count(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  crossAxisCount: 1,
                                  children: List.generate(10, (index) {
                                    return Image.network(
                                      "https://via.placeholder.com/200",
                                    );
                                  })))

                    ])))));
  }
```

Any takers? I can't seem to figure this one out;

Comment: Are you wanting the card to continue to grow with the more items you add to it or are you expecting the card to be a specific height?

Comment: Hi Matt, I want it to continue to grow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I managed to figure this one out.
The `SingleChildScrollView` needs to sit inside your Padding which is the parent widget for your body.
Your `Card` needs to be the child of the `SingleChildScrollView`.

This code should work for you.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Company name'),
      leading: new IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context, true);
        }
      )
    ),
    body: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Card(
            child: Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      height: 120,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  width: 100,
                                  height: 100,
                                  child: Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/200"))),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 20, 10, 0),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text('Company name',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    Text('Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum')
                                  ],
                                )),
                          )
                        ],
                      )),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 20, right: 20),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text('Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25)),
                            Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.thumb_up,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20)),
                                Text('Lorem ipsum lorem',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 18))
                            ],
                          )
                        ]
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
}
}
```

**PS** I changed some colours just to see the UI displaying on the screen.

Comment: And if someone don't want padding just `ZERO` the `padding` this way `padding: EdgeInsets.all(0)`.

Comment: What is changed again?

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: @eqrakhattak can you elaborate about what specifically doesn't work so someone can help you? Maybe raise your own question.

Answer (score 7):

I came across this and my issue was that I had my `SingleChildScrollView` as a child of a column.

I fixed it by wrapping my `SingleChildScrollView` in an `Expanded` widget

Comment: not exactly this case.

Comment: gives error: "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget."