# SinglePageScrollView is not working in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am learning flutter right now and my **SinglePageScrollView** is not working, Please help me out, I am trying to solve it since 10 hours, I am just brewww right now.

This is my code btw

```
SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            child: Image.asset("assets/images/img.jpg"),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            child: const Text(
                              "Hii, This is what i probably uploaded",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Divider(color: Colors.black)
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            child: Image.asset("assets/images/img.jpg"),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            child: const Text(
                              "Hii, This is what i probably uploaded",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Divider(color: Colors.black)
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Btw, ***SingleChildScrollView*** is the child of ***Row*** widget

[image: This Screenshot can explain more]

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54799003/singlechildscrollview-wont-work-placement out. It might help

Comment: Add container height as "MediaQuery.of(context).size.height"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly, it has only one small mistake,

SingleChildScrollview always need some height means in how much area we want scroll our child widgets.

You’ve 2 widgets in your Column

1. Row
2. SingleChildScrollview

You want to scroll your child widgets in Column except Row area, so wrap it within Expanded

```
Expanded(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
….
```

Answer (score 0):

Row must have children or you have an unclosed parenthesis in the container.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(),
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);


return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Row(),
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```